# Are there any dangers in working outside in a storm?

Tags: stardew-valley

It just started storming today. Am I in any danger of getting struck by lighting if I go outside and do stuff? If so, what are the effects of getting struck?

Comment: I saw a tree fall over by itself once during a storm, but I don't think it can hurt you.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't dangerous. The only effect of storms AFAIK is to charge up Battery packs if you have lightning rods placed. Otherwise it's considered as normal rain for fishing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, some of your crops can die in a thunderstorm, I suspect. Although, I didn't actually see the lightning hitting the specific crops, there was no other reason for the crops to have died, they had been watered every day, I had scarecrows very close to those crops, and they were warded off from the outside.